# add a div inside a td jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a div inside a td.

My td before

```
<td>Fiction</td>
```

After i write code

```
var cell =  getCell(indexRow + 1, colIndex);
var wrap = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'container');

cell.append(wrap);
```

Now it becomes

```
<td> Fiction [object Object] </td>
```

javascript

```
function getCell(row, col){

    var currentRow = $('#MapDetails tr')[row];
    var cell = $(currentRow).find('td')[col];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try using `$("<div id=id></div>")`

Comment: nope... i want that the text fiction goes inside a div

Comment: I tested your code with only one cell and it `append` works fine `<td>Fiction<div id="container"></div></td>`

Comment: no it is showing me <td>Fiction [object Object]</td> however i want <td><div id= id>Fiction</div></td>

Comment: `append` will insert new content to the end of selected element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a couple syntax errors.

Look this code and feel free to ask questions...

```js
function getCell(row, col){

  var currentRow = $('#MapDetails tr');
  var cell = currentRow.eq(row).find('td').eq(col);

  return cell;
}

var indexRow = 0;
var colIndex = 0;

var cell =  getCell(indexRow + 1, colIndex);
var wrap = $('<div>').attr('id', 'container').text("I'm the new div!");
cell.append(wrap);
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
td div{
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="MapDetails">
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fiction</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Now nothing happens to the cell it remains <td>Fiction</td>

Comment: Well If you run the snippet above, you should see it works. So check for what differs in your project.

Comment: could it be because i am putting a kendo wrapper on the table? That should be the case i recon

Comment: No. You can wrap the table with whatever you wish. I would look for the variables `indexRow` and `colIndex` you're passing to the function. Try to console log them and see if it is logic for your table structure. The `.eq()` function accepts a zero-based integer.

Comment: I can see that your code is working..now i have removed the kendo wrapper from table so i can say wrapper is not the problem when i type in browser console getCell(2,6) it returns me the correct cell..then i hard coded the same in my application..it still returns <td>Fiction [object Object]</td>

Comment: Do you have a live link to share so I can see it ?

Comment: not sure how to create a link like you did...i have a sample application though

Comment: In the function, you have `var cell = currentRow.eq(row).find('td').eq(col);` **OR** `var cell = $(currentRow).eq(row).find('td').eq(col);` ??? If you have the second one... Just remove the `$` and parenthesis around the `currentRow` variable... And I meant a link to your website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145164/discussion-between-samra-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 0):

[`.attr(key, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) only sets the attributes to the jQuery object.

You might want to create one with the specific attributes by following code.

```
var cell =  getCell(indexRow + 1, colIndex);
var wrap = $('<div />', {id: 'container'});

cell.append(wrap);
```

Or If you want `wrap` to be the only element inside `<td>` then

```
cell.html(wrap);
```

Comment: How about using `.html()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use hmlt instead of append 
Hope this will solve using html like this
 cell.html(""),
Let me know if this doesn't work,

Comment: nope i added cell.innerHtml and it was undefined..mainly because it is a jquery object not an Html object

Comment: Should be something wrong in your getCell function then

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        var indexRow = 0;
        var colIndex = 0;
        var cell = getCell(indexRow + 1, colIndex),
          $cell = $(cell);
        var wrap = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'container').text($cell.text());

        $cell.html(wrap);

        function getCell(row, col) {
          var currentRow = $('#MapDetails tr')[row];
          var cell = $(currentRow).find('td')[col];

          return cell;
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="MapDetails">
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Samra</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Debasis</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```